# Como un proyecto biblioteca puede escribir en statusbar de otro proyecto, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una solución de **2 proyectos**, una es bibliotecas y el principal es el de formularios. El principal tiene como referencia a la biblioteca.

Como es sabido, no se puede colocar referencia a su vez en biblioteca porque se crea un "*circulo de dependencias*". Por lo tanto, no se como llamar a la barra de estado de el proyecto principal para cambiar las propiedades del mismo, como "**Text**". Existe alguna forma?

Comment: Si. No intentando modificar nada de la aplicacion principal desde la biblioteca. Si la biblioteca quiere modificar el `Text` de un formulario, en lugar de eso debe devolver ese `Text` y que sea la app principal la que lo modifique.

Comment: como se hace eso? se puede enviar informacion desde la biblioteca hacia el prinipal? como?

Comment: Depende mucho de que es lo que pretendes conseguir. O bien llamas desde el principal a un metodo de la libreria y esta devolverá lo que necesites, o bien puedes crear un evento personalizado en la libreria al que debes suscribirte desde el principal y que devuelva la informacion.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a pikoh pude realizar la siguiente solucion!!
En un modulo declarado publico, hice la siguiente funcion

```
Public Sub mensaje(mensaje As String, Optional eserror As Boolean = False, Optional informar As Boolean = False)
        If mensaje.Equals("") Then Exit Sub
        intercomunicacion.mensaje(mensaje, eserror, informar)
    End Sub
```

Y tengo una clase vinculatoria entre ambos proyectos que es la siguiente:

```
Public Class intercomunicacion
Public Shared Property notificacion_cuerpo As String = ""
    Public Shared Property notificacion_titulo As String = ""
Public Shared Sub mensaje(texto As String, Optional eserror As Boolean = False, Optional informarmensaje As Boolean = False)
        _texto = texto
        _eserror = eserror
        _informarmensaje = informarmensaje
        RaiseEvent enviarmensaje()
    End Sub
Public Shared Event enviarmensaje()
End Class
```

En el formulario principal del proyecto principal esta a siguiente funcion

```
 Private Sub enviarmensaje()
        mensaje(intercomunicacion.texto, intercomunicacion.eserror)
        If intercomunicacion.informarmensaje Then
            ventana(intercomunicacion.texto, "Atención")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Y en el load de este formulario esta la siguiente línea

```
 AddHandler intercomunicacion.enviarmensaje, AddressOf enviarmensaje
```

Desde el proyecto de biblioteca (secundario) llaman a la función mensaje, este se contacta a travez de un evento  al proyecto principal. Espero que les sirva!